# How to delete multiple rows in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, datarow

How can I delete specific DataRows within a loop of a DataTable rows which meet a custom condition -lets say the rows having an index of even number-? (Without using LINQ)

Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**It depends on what you mean by 'delete'.**

*If you mean mark them as deleted*, just call the `Delete()` method on each row as you visit it in your loop. You then need to call `AcceptChanges()` on the data table to finalize the delete - presumably after you update your database (if one is involved).

```
foreach( DataRow row in someTable.Rows )
{
    if( /* your condition here */ )
        row.Delete();
}
someTable.AcceptChanges();
```

*If you mean remove it from the DataTable, then you need to do so in two passes:*

```
List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
foreach( DataRow row in someTable.Rows )
{
    if( /* your condition here */ )
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add( row );
    }
}

foreach( DataRow row in rowsToDelete )
{
    someTable.Rows.Remove( row );
}
```

It's worth pointing out that you can always use the first method to remove rows - since marking rows as `Deleted` and then accepting changes will automatically remove them from the table. But, sometimes it is more clear and efficient to simply remove the `DataRow` objects from the `Rows` collection.

Comment: If you do the same as what LBushkin said,you will see as follow:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
so it is wrong.

Comment: As long as you call .AcceptChanges() prior to marking rows as deleted (before the foreach loop) then you will not get the "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute" error. The error appears because there are pending changes that need to be accepted. If you use a for loop then it won't matter but in that case it would be best to iterate backwards.

Comment: the first method outputs what Szjdw said but the second one works like magic, thanks Bush!

Comment: Using of `Remove()` is not recommended in a `foreach` loop since the function changes the state of the collection.

Comment: The second option works like a charm, the first one will give an error...

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this example

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Foo",typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    table.Rows.Add(i);

for (int i = table.Rows.Count -1; i >=0; i--)
{
    // sample removes all even foos
    if ((int)table.Rows[i]["Foo"] % 2 == 0)
        table.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Could also do a forward loop (0 -> Count-1) if you move the `i++` inside the for loop and only increment when not deleting.  `if (...) remove() else i++`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a shorter solution than those proposed above, try looping over the list of results, and using a *lambda* like `sub(x)` to remove each of those rows.

```
dt.Select("Column1 > 0").ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) dt.Rows.Remove(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

The other way is

```
    DataRow[] DrArrCheck = DataTableName.Select("ID > 0");
    foreach(DataRow DrCheck in DrArrCheck)
    {
        DataTableName.Rows.Remove(DrCheck);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete multiple rows (for instance 50,000 out of 100,000) it is much quicker to copy the database than to do either datatable.Rows.Remove(row) or row.Delete(). For instance:

```
DataRow[] rowsToKeep = datatable.Select("ID > 50000");
DataTable tempDataTable= rowsToKeep.CopyToDataTable;
dataTable.Clear();
dataTable.Merge(tempDataTable);
tempDataTable.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void DeleteRowsFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, string columnName, string columnValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<DataRow> dataRows = (from t in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                             where t.Field<string>(columnName) == columnValue
                                             select t);
            foreach (DataRow row in dataRows)
                dataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try iterating over the result of Select().  This is pretty similar to other answers, but I find it the most direct

```
DataRow[] r = table.Select();
for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        r[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always used LBushkin's "two-phase" approach and I finally decided it was worth it to write a function for it:

```
    public delegate bool DataRowComparer(DataRow dr);

    public static void RemoveDataRows(DataTable table, DataRowComparer drc)
    {
        List<DataRow> RowsToRemove = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            if (drc(dr))
                RowsToRemove.Add(dr);
        foreach (DataRow dr in RowsToRemove)
            table.Rows.Remove(dr);
    }
```

And now I can delete rows with one line of code (for example):

```
RemoveDataRows(dt, row => row["StringVal"].ToString() == "B" && (Int16)(row["NumberVal"]) >= 4);
```

In case this helps anyone...

(And any ways to further abbreviate are appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
    for (int i = RowNumber.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(Int32.Parse(RowNumber[i]));
                        }

                        missingNotesGV.DataSource = dt;

                        missingNotesGV.DataBind();
```

Its important to do the for loop in reverse otherwise you get errors if you're removing rows at the end in addition to rows in other places.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it when I ran into this issue.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim count As Integer = resultsDT.Rows.Count - 1
For i As Integer = 0 To count
    If resultsDT.Rows(index).Item("something") = "something" Then                               
        resultsDT.Rows(index).Delete()
        resultsDT.AcceptChanges()
        index = index - 1
    End If
    index = index + 1
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
foreach(DataRow oRow in YourDataTable.Rows)
{
  if ("Check You Condition")
   {
      YourDataTable.Rows.Remove(oRow);
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while iterating through it with a foreach loop.